# WAMP not connecting to my Android phone

Tags: android, wamp

I followed the **1st and 2nd answers** from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device) to connect my WAMP SERVER to my Android phone but the issue is that when ever I try to access the IP address through my phone browser, I get error Message from my browser saying am offline.

I guess it works better when offline. When I try going online on my mobile the site take like forever to load and yet doesn't load up.

Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: what address are you using in your mobile browser to access?

Comment: share info about your network and your server ip address, please